# Can Scanner.next() return null or empty string?

Tags: java, input

I'm learning Java coming from other programming languages (Js, C and others..)

I'm wondering if under any circumstances the `Scanner.next()` method could return (without throwing) an invalid string or less than one character (ie. `null` or empty string `""`). I'm used to double-check user input for any possible unexpected/invalid value, but I wanted to know if testing for `null` and `myString.length() < 1` is always unnecessary or could be useful/needed.

I'm asking in particular when reading from the commandline and `System.in`, not from other Streams of Files. Can I safely get the first character with `myString.charAt(0)` from the returned value when reading normally from the terminal input (ie. no pipes and no files, straight from terminal and keyboard)?

I searched the Java SE 9 API Docs and couldn't find mentions about possibly unexpected return values. In case anything goes wrong with input it should just throw an Exception, right?

Example (part of main method without imports):

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter a selection (from A to E): ");
String res = keyboard.next();

if (res == null || res.length() < 1) {
    // Unnecessary if?
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--

"Returns:
the next token
Throws:
NoSuchElementException - if no more tokens are available
IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed"

Comment: you check for `hasNext()` before `next()` which guarantees that there is a next element

Comment: So, I should always call `Scanner.hasNext​()` even if stdin/System.in is empty and the user didn't type anything?

Comment: That would be usual way of dealing with input using Scanner.

Comment: @Zorgatone, please don't edit the post changing its content rather add it at the bottom stating _*edit*_ to indicate that you've edited the post. thanks

Comment: @Aominè somebody once told me [the world... err no, actually] not to write edit inside questions, because you can altrady see changes. Here I forgot to mention some details

Comment: A useful rule to remember:  In Java SE, `null` is an abnormal value.  If the documentation doesn’t specifically say it can return null, it won’t return null.  If the documentation doesn’t specifically say that null is a valid argument, it’s not.

Comment: @VGR thanks, that's the most useful comment here. I'm not used to treat null as abnormal and I use it a lot in JavaScript (I know they aren't the same, of course). I must familiarize with Java and its documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Scanner#next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) can *never* return null and if the user enters an empty string or a string containing whitespaces only then the method will block and wait for input to scan.

Therefore the `if` condition is redundant and is not needed at all.

Comment: I'm reading from `System.in`, I was thinking maybe if the users presses enter without typing anything before, I wouldn't get an empty string and by default it would just show an empty line and still wait for at least a valid letter/space in the input, (just like in C) right?

Comment: Well it may return `null` String :P

Comment: @AniketSahrawat you mean `"null"`?

Comment: @Zorgatone yeah, that's what i mean

Comment: @Zorgatone he did say "null String"

Comment: @Zorgatone everything is stated in the java doc. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next-- . Also, you can do some testing with `String input = scanner.next();
          System.out.println("test");` then enter an empty string you'll see that "test" will never get printed and if you enter whitespace only then again "test" will never get printed.

Comment: @Aominè I have read the API, I was asking if there were some cases where you could get null or an empty string. From what I tried I couldn't enter an input string, but you never know on some systems or when using pipes ex. "progName < inputFile.txt". At least I'm confident that from normal input it shouldn't...

Comment: @Zorgatone there is no case in which `Scanner#next` would return `null` or an _empty string_ unless it's a bug which is _very very very unlikey_.

Answer (score 2):

`Scanner.next` can never return null by looking at its source code. From Scanner.next code

```
while(true){ 
...
if (token != null) {
      matchValid = true;
      skipped = false;
      return token;
 }
 ...
}
```

It can throw `NoSuchElementException` if no more tokens are available or `IllegalStateException` if the scanner is closed according to the docs. So your checks are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following input:

```
    a b c
    d e
    f
    g
```

The breakdown below shows how a certain sequence of calls to a Scanner object, , will read the above input:

A call to scan.next(); returns the next token, a.
A call to scan.next(); returns the next token, b.
A call to scan.nextLine(); returns the next token, c. It's important to note that the scanner returns a space and a letter, because it's reading from the end of the last token until the beginning of the next line.
A call to scan.nextLine(); returns the contents of the next line, d e.
A call to scan.next(); returns the next token, f.
A call to scan.nextLine(); returns everything after f until the beginning of the next line; because there are no characters there, it returns an empty String.
A call to scan.nextLine(); returns g.