# Program doesn't print anything until Scanner#nextLine() received not a "blank space" nor "enter"

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, system.out

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (in.hasNext()) {
    String a = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(a + " 1");
}
```

I just wanna check what will happen when input is SPACE or ENTER, but it doesn't print anything until my input is neither SPACE nor ENTER, like this

```
a                     // input 
a 1                   // output 
                      // SPACE(input) 
c                     // input
  1                   // output
c 1                   // output
```

Why doesn't it print until it reads something which is neither BLANK nor SPACE? also, when it finally print, it print the SPACE which is the the line before c 1, when i input c, it give me 1  and c 1.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `hasNext()`? What does it wait for?

Comment: Or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47971568/can-scanner-next-return-null-or-empty-string

Comment: In your own words, why *should* it print immediately when a space is typed? What do you think `hasNext` is doing? Now, check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()). Does it meet your expectation? What do you think a `token` is? What do you think `This method may block while...` means in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Java Scanner hasNext() vs. hasNextLine():](https://www.baeldung.com/java-scanner-hasnext-vs-hasnextline)
> That is, `hasNext()` checks the input and returns true if it has another `non-whitespace` character.
> `Whitespace` includes not only the space character, but also tab space (\t), line feed (\n), and even more characters.
> **Continuous whitespace characters are treated as a single delimiter.**

**System.in** means **Standard Input**.
When you pass **System.in** to init the **Scanner**,  it will read data from **Standard Input**.
And it will always waiting for the input unless your input is `EOF`(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> in `Windows` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>).
So the scanner will always waiting for a **non-whitespace** character from input.

#### Input

When you press <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it sends two **whitespace** character   `\n` to the **Standard Input**, and the function `scanner.hasNext()` is still waiting for a **non-whitespace** character. And `scanner.hasNext()` doesn't return anything. That's why there is no output at this time.
Then you press <kbd>c</kbd>, it sends **non-whitespace** character `c` to the **Standard Input**.

#### Output

Now your **Standard Input** contains   `\n` `c`, the third one is not a **whitespace** character.
Finally the function `scanner.hasNext()` **returns true**.
Then the `scanner.nextLine()` read a line till character `\n`: it will be   (one character),
and program print    `1`.

**Standard Input** now becomes `c`, only one character,
which will cause `scanner.hasNext()` to return true again:
Scanner will read a line, which will be one character `c`,
and print `c`  `1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did check the documentation as previous comments suggested, but i missed the point that u mentioned on the output section,"Standard Input now becomes c". i do make a stupid mistake. thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

As mentionned by @Savior from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993377/why-is-hasnext-false-but-hasnextline-is-true) :

> `hasNext()` checks to see if there is a parseable token in the buffer, as separated by the scanner's delimiter.
> Since the scanner's delimiter is whitespace, and the linePattern is also white space, it is possible for there to be a linePattern in the buffer but no parseable tokens.

Consider using `hasNextLine()`

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String a = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(a + " 1");
        }
    }
}
```